# jQuery PNG transparent MouseHover

Tags: jquery, png, mousehover

I have following problem. I have a team page like this example: http://www.social-markets.de/social-commerce-team.html small circle team pictures and want to add via jQuery a PNG transparent MouseHover PNG image with pink circle for the small circles on bottom. Have anybody a idea?

Comment: Why can't you do it like the bigger circles at the top? Is there a particular reason, then please specify as it may get you a better answer

Comment: another suggestion

you can also make only one copy of the circular image...(since it is visible only on one image at a time.

Then you can set the offset of that image according to the image hovered on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hide the additional info via CSS (`display:none`) and toggle it on hover. Sth like:

```
$('.elementWithExtra').hover(function(){
$(this).children('.extra').toggle();
}, function(){
$(this).children('.extra').toggle();
});
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/hover/ and http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".imgDiv").mouseover(function(){
  $(this).children(".hiddenImgDiv").show();  
}).mouseout(function(){
  $(this).children(".hiddenImgDiv").hide();  
});
```

Comment: You should use classes instead of IDs as there will be several elements. Also `mouseover` and `mouseout`don't have capitalized Os

Comment: I dont think that having a child with same id would be any problem if we are refering through its parent element

Comment: Having more than one element with the same ID will always be a problem. "What makes attributes of type ID special is that no two such attributes can have the same value; whatever the document language, an ID attribute can be used to uniquely identify its element." -> http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#id-selectors

Comment: got you thanks for the link...
corrected too...!
but I still don't see how will it hinder the working

Comment: It should probably work but it will generate invalid HTML. Therefore I'd opt for the classes.